# how can I invoke another msi packet in one msi custom action?

Tags: installation, wix

Can anybody tell me how can I invoke another msi packet in one msi custom action with wix?

Answer (score 1):

You can't; MSI doesn't support running multiple install transactions simultaneously. You need to use an external program (bootstrapper/chainer) to install the packages in a chain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use a bootstrapper for the job. I have been denying this fact for an extended period of time (thinking "what!? this supposedly advanced thingie can't even do this?) and I finally accepted it.

Here's a post to aid your journey:

http://wix.mindcapers.com/wiki/Bootstrapper

Comment: thanks, it seems bootstrapper is my only option, but what make me confused is i can not find much doc or resource about it, i can not even find the download link of Visual Studio .NET 2005 Framework Bootstrapper Plug-in? can you give me more info about it?

Comment: @Defan: I haven't tried those bootstrappers. What I did was to use a simple .bat file to call `msiexec` on each MSI file. I wrap everything into one EXE file using `iexpress` (comes with Windows, just type it in your command prompt). I then use various other tools to change the icons, descriptions, etc. of that EXE file. Hope it helps.